# input in C programming language

Tags: c

I want code receive from user a floating number but store only two digit after decimal point

for example if user input

```
a=123.123456789
```

a value will equal 123.12

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func(int x,int digit,int con,char* s)
{
        int v;
        v=x/digit;
        v=v*digit;
        x-=v;
        if(con==1){
           printf("%d %s(s) de R$ %.2f\n",(v/digit),s,(float)digit/100);
            return x;
        }
        printf("%d %s(s) de R$ %.2f\n",(v/digit),s,(float)digit);
        return x;
}
int main() {
    int x=0;
    float y;//if change to double the result will be true
    scanf("%f",&y);
    //y = ((int)(100.0 * y)) / 100.0;
    x=(int)y;
    y=y-x;

    printf("NOTAS:\n");

    char* arr="nota";
    x=func(x,100,0,arr);
    x=func(x,50,0,arr);
    x=func(x,20,0,arr);
    x=func(x,10,0,arr);
    x=func(x,5,0,arr);
    x=func(x,2,0,arr);
    printf("MOEDAS:\n");
    arr="moeda";
    x=func(x,1,0,arr);
    //mod
    x=y*100;
    x=func(x,50,1,arr);
    x=func(x,25,1,arr);
    x=func(x,10,1,arr);
    x=func(x,5,1,arr);
    x=func(x,1,1,arr);

    return 0;
}
```

problem will found in:
https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1021

Comment: Can you post the code that you have written to try to achieve that?

Comment: I'll go ahead and remove the c++ tag. It's either C (like you say in the title), or C++. Never both.

Comment: @iharob in any regular program

Comment: @MarcusMüller sorry :D

Comment: @MohamedSlama محمد Can you explain why you want that? Don't you see that there is no point in doing that?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "stored" at only two decimals. You might mean you want to only *print* 2 decimals, and that you can do without affecting how the number is stored--just let it be what it is. If you actually want to truncate the number itself, you can do that too--but be aware that your result might not be exactly representable in floating point.

Comment: @iharob
float x;
    scanf("%f",&x);
    x=x*1.5;
    printf("%f",x);

Comment: @MohamedSlama محمد سلامة That is not an example of a use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value have only 2 decimal places is a matter of displaying it, so you just need to print the number of decimal places you are interested in, like

```
float value = 123.123456;

printf("%.2f\n", value);
```

if you want to dynamicaly specify that number, you can use

```
float value    = 123.123456;
int   decimals = 2;

printf("%.*f\n", decimals, value);
```

If you want to **store** the value as a string then use `sprintf()` or better `snprintf()`.

And taking the input with only two decimals does not make sense anyway because the output is what should be filtered instead of the input, note that after all you will ignore the extra decimals inserted by the user.

Also, note that floating point numbers cannot store exact numbers, so even i you leave only two decimal places by doing something like

```
float value = ((int)(100.0 * 123.1234156)) / 100.0
```

the actual value that is stored might be

```
123.1200000001
```

which has more decimal places.

One thing that you could try is

```
struct RealNumber
{
    int integerPart;
    int decimalPart;
};
```

and then handle the input to read them separately, which will be really dificult.

Comment: Storing that doesn't make any sense, and that is of course impossible. And I did mention that you can store a string ... read the full answer.

Comment: in c there`s an input function like :
scanf("%2f",a);
it only store to digit 
i wanna an function like ("%.2f") in the print function you made

Comment: There is no reason to need such function. Please read my answer, the whole answer and try to understand that computers do not understand numbers as humans do, specially not floating point numbers.

Comment: thanks for your notes but i have problem with this code 
in this case if user input 12.73 in value it will store12.72 
i don`t know the reason but the solution to change it to double

Comment: @MohamedSlama remember the `123.1200000001` part, it's not really `12.73` or `12.72` and you could use `ceil()` or `floor()` or `round()` instead of just casting, though the cast will still be neede because all these functions return floating point numbers.

Comment: @MohamedSlama you can't, wait until you can answer some question or you ask a well received question to raise your reputation.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to round off to two decimal points you could try something like:

```
a = ((int) (a*100))/100.0;
```

Comment: in this case if user input 12.73 a value will be 12.72